# Selection Sort Method

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist, selection-sort

So this is a somewhat silly question, but I'm having an issue with my selectionSort method on a class. It is swapping the ArrayList data every time instead of just when one item is smaller. I know it's a bracket issue, but I'm lost on where to remove/add brackets.

```
// Sort using selectionSort and call compareTo methods to evaluate
public static ArrayList selectionSort(ArrayList<Person> array) {
    int smallestIndex;
    Person smallestValue;

    for (int index = 1; index < array.size(); index++) {
        smallestValue = array.get(index);
        smallestIndex = index;

        for (int i = index + 1; i < array.size(); i++) {
            if (smallestValue.compareTo(array.get(i)) == 1) 
            {
                // update smallest
                smallestValue = array.get(i);
                smallestIndex = i;
            }
            // do nothing if the curIndex has the smallest value
            else if (smallestIndex == index)
                ;
            // swap values otherwise else
            else {
                Person temp = array.get(index);
                array.set(index, array.get(smallestIndex));
                array.set(smallestIndex, temp);

            }
        }
    }
    return array;
}
```

Comment: `index` should not start from 0? plz post `Person` object

Comment: Hi Actually `compareTo()` works for `String` as Parameter But I can see here that you are actually using an Object `Person` Does that Class Overrides `compareTo` method ? Then Please post `Person` Class how you are overriding since you said every iteration its swapping elements your overriding logic could have been wrong,

Comment: You should read about how `compareTo()` works: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html

Answer (score 0):

class Sort {

```
private List<Integer> list;

public Sort(List<Integer> list){
    this.list = list;       
}

public void selectionSort() {
    int idx = 0;
    int temp = 0;
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++) {
        temp = list.get(i);
        for(int j=i; j<list.size(); j++){
            if(list.get(j) <= temp){
                temp = list.get(j);
                idx = j;                    
            }
        }
        swap(i,idx);
    }

}

private void swap(int x, int y) {
    int tmp = list.get(x);
    list.set(x, list.get(y));
    list.set(y, tmp);
}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

You can use `Collections.sort()`